# how to get number of clients for a username in a message VPN

Tags: solace

after upgrade to SolOS 9.4

/SEMP/v2/monitor/msgVpns/vpn-xxx/clientUsernames

is giving output as

```
        "aclProfileName":"",
        "clientProfileName":"",
        "clientUsername":"",
        "dynamic":false,
        "enabled":true,
        "guaranteedEndpointPermissionOverrideEnabled":false,
        "msgVpnName":"vpn-xxx",
        "subscriptionManagerEnabled":false
```

earlier in 9.0 OS  numClient was coming in response, which is not not coming in 9.4

```
        "aclProfileName":"",
        "authorizationGroup":"",
        "clientProfileName":"",
        "clientUsername":"",
        "clientUsernameDeniedLoginClientUsernameShutdown":0,
        "dynamicallyConfigured":false,
        "enabled":true,
        "guaranteedEndpointPermissionOverrideEnabled":false,
        "maxConnections":200000,
        "maxConnectionsServiceSmf":30000,
        "maxConnectionsServiceWeb":200000,
        "maxEndpoints":16000,
        "msgVpnName":"vpn-xxx",
        **"numClients":0,
        "numClientsServiceSmf":0,
        "numClientsServiceWeb":0,
        "numEndpoints":37,**
        "passwordConfigured":true,
        "subscriptionManagerEnabled":false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SolOS 9.0, the monitor API (SEMP/v2/monitor/...) was not yet released. The output referenced from 9.0 is part of the undocumented private API which was not supported and was subject to change. This is why the fields are no longer available on upgrade to SolOS 9.4.

In SolOS 9.4, this information can be obtained using legacy SEMP.